# What is the significance of initializing direction arrays below with given values when developing chess program?

Tags: c++, c, chess

I am new to competitive programming, and I noticed frequently, many of the great coders have these four lines in their code (particularly in those involving arrays):

```
int di[] = { 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1 };
int dj[] = { 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1 };
int diK[] = { -2, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -1 };
int djK[] = { -1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2 };
```

What does this really signify and what is technique used for?

Comment: I often use `d={0,1,0,-1,0}` for this: item pairs for `d[i], d[i+1]` give me four cardinal directions.

Answer (score 85):

This is a technique to encode all directions as arrays - every pair of `di[i],dj[i]` is a different direction.

If we imagine we have a piece at a location x,y, and we want to add onto its x and its y value to move it to a nearby location, 1,0 is east, -1,0 is west, 0,1 is south, 0,-1 is north and so on.

(Here I have said top left is 0,0 and bottom right is 4,4 and shown what move each index of the arrays will make from the central point, X, at 2,2.)

```
.....
.536.
.1X0.
.724.
.....
```

The way it is set up, if you do `^1` (`^` being bitwise XOR) on the index you get the opposite direction - 0 and 1 are opposites, 2 and 3 are opposites and so on. (Another way to set it up is to go clockwise starting at north - then `^4` gets you the opposite direction.)

Now you can test all directions from a given point by looping over your `di` and `dj` arrays, instead of needing to write out each direction on its own line (for eight in total!) (Just don't forget to do bounds checking :) )

`diK` and `djK` form all [knights directions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_%28chess%29) instead of all adjacent directions. Here, `^1` will flip along one axis, `^4` will give the opposite knight leap.

```
.7.6.
0...5
..K..
1...4
.2.3.
```

Comment: what are 'knights directions'?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer..
Could you please link me or perhaps show me some code to better illustrate it..(I am a bit novice ..if u could understand:) Thanks again

Comment: I applaud Patashu's attempt at an answer. While it seems that many have understood his explanation, I have not been able to understand it well. If anyone can add to what has already been said, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @deepak Imagine a position is represented by an `x,y` tuple in 2D space. For each pair of `di[i], dj[i]` add it to `x,y` and you'll get `x,y` transposed in each direction one by one. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Patashu Yeah I think i get it now. I was mostly confused about the figures you had drawn and how you got them. I finally understood those figures.

Answer (score 65):

For those finding Patashu's explanation difficult to follow, I'll attempt to clarify.

Imagine you are trying to consider every possible move from a given point on a chess board.

If you loop over the di and dj arrays, interpreting the di values as x offsets and the dj values as y offsets, you cover each of the possible 8 directions.

Assuming positive x is east and positive y is south (as in Patashu's answer), you get the following;

```
  | di/x | dj/y | Direction
--+------+------+-----------
0 |   1  |   0  | east
1 |  -1  |   0  | west
2 |   0  |   1  | south 
3 |   0  |  -1  | north
4 |   1  |   1  | south-east
5 |  -1  |  -1  | north-west
6 |   1  |  -1  | north-east
7 |  -1  |   1  | south-west
```

The diK and djK arrays can be interpreted the same way to establish the possible moves for the Knight piece. If you're not familiar with chess, the Knight moves in an L pattern - two squares in one direction, and then one square at right angles to that (or vice versa).

```
  | diK/x | djK/y | Direction
--+-------+-------+----------------
0 |  -2   |  -1   | 2 west, 1 north
1 |  -2   |   1   | 2 west, 1 south
2 |  -1   |   2   | 1 west, 2 south
3 |   1   |   2   | 1 east, 2 south
4 |   2   |   1   | 2 east, 1 south
5 |   2   |  -1   | 2 east, 1 north
6 |   1   |  -2   | 1 east, 2 north
7 |  -1   |  -2   | 1 west, 2 north
```

Answer (score 1):

A small snippet of code to check the amount of moves possible in all directions, which uses the defined arrays.

```
int di[] = { 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1 };
int dj[] = { 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1 };
int movesPossible[8];
int move = 0;
int posx, posy; // position of the figure we are checking

for (int d=0; d<8; d++) {
  for (move = 1; board.getElt(posx+di[d]*move, posy+dj[d]*move)==EMPTY; move++) ;
  movesPossible[d] = move-1;
}
```